# Issue with Laravel breeze api and sanctum CSRF Token cookie

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, csrf-token, laravel-breeze

Im trying to learn react, i alredy did laravel, so the problem im facign is that i mtrying to make the login from my front end react app, the problem (as i alredy debbuged most of it) its in laravel.

Thne first steps were to insatll breeze into my laravel project 10.x with composer,
then i made the project only api with php artisan breeze:install api.

so inr eturn i dont have anymroe the blade files, but only controllers and other files in roder to set up a proper login and register actions with axios in my react project.

the problem now, as i used to test axios from my dev build and Postman for the api routes, i get `419 unknown status`, all the time, even if i send a custom property to the body with raw JSON.

.env file

```
APP_NAME=portfolio-custom
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY='key'
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:5173
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:5173
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

cors.php config

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL')],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

unfortuntely my axios call is trying to read the token, but there is no cookie token in my laravel project and i mtrying to see why it will not show properly
axios error from react

```
config: Object { timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }
​​
adapter: Array [ "xhr", "http" ]
​​
baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
​​
data: '{"email":"test@mail.com","password":"password12345"}'
​​
env: Object { FormData: (), Blob: () }
​​
headers: Object { Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Content-Type": "application/json" }
​​
maxBodyLength: -1
​​
maxContentLength: -1
​​
method: "post"
​​
timeout: 0
​​
transformRequest: Array [ transformRequest(data, headers)
 ]
​​
transformResponse: Array [ transformResponse(data)
 ]
​​
transitional: Object { silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false }
​​
url: "/login"
​​
validateStatus: function validateStatus(status)
​​
withCredentials: true
​​
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
​​
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
message: "Request failed with status code 419"
​
name: "AxiosError"
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, … }
​
response: Object { data: {…}, status: 419, statusText: "unknown status", … }
```

i tried some guides and i come across couple solution btu the prorblem is that i dont ahve anymore balde fiels to make the meta tag solution to take the src toke work, so i need to unserstand why the token doesnt show up in the cookies.

Howver te sse wll be wt ts warg  get fro laravel
`23:15:37.850 Cookie “XSRF-TOKEN” was rejected for invalid domain.`
`23:15:37.850 Cookie “portfolio-custom” was rejected for invalid domain.`

Comment: Hi, have you passed the csrf_token field which calling the axios request?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you are still searching for solution but I encountered the same error just today. The problem was that breeze puts it's auth routes in the web.php file. Normally web.php routes are intended for monolithic app (using blade view or stuff like Livewire) and not API app. Thus Laravel has middleware specially hooked to the web.php routes to look for crsf token. If you move those auth routes to the api.php routes file the 419 error will no longer occur. Other thing is to make pre request to Laravel to receive a crsf token to include it in the follow-up request. From my limited knowledge (if I am wrong someone can correct me) building a Laravel API that uses sanctum type API tokens or jwt type token you kinda don't need the crsf token since you are not using Laravel as a full stack solution. Hope this info helps.